# How to assign date to Temporal date field in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

I have an entity with field of type Date and I have annotated it with `@Temporal(DATE)`.Now how do I store value in this filed? Using a set method or its automatically created?

Here's my code:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date deleted_At;

        

java.util.Date javaDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(javaDate.getTime());
clientToDelete.setDeleted_At(sqlDate);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.util.Date` nor `java.sql.Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And set its value by using like `LocalDate.of(2021, Month.JUNE, 5)`.

Comment: And don‘t use underscores in variable names.

Comment: any specific reason for that @Jens?

Comment: @rudeTool Because the [Naming Conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1-300) section of [The Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) says that [Field Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1-350) (and Local Variable and Parameter Names) "should be in mixed case with a lowercase first letter and the first letters of subsequent words capitalized."

Comment: @rudeTool Because we don’t use underscores in names in Java (except for constants), so readers of your code (of which you will hope to have many on Stack Overflow) will stumble and wonder until they think, *wel, it‘s just an underscore*, which will distract us when trying to understand and answer your question. (You also noticed that on purpose I left out the underscore in my answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time

I recommend you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. The class to use for a date without time of day is `LocalDate`.

```
private LocalDate deletedAt;
```

(No annotation necessary.) To set it to today’s date:

```
    clientToDelete.setDeletedAt(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
```

java.time is supported since Hibernate 5.

If you cannot change the type of the field, still use `LocalDate` for setting the value:

```
    clientToDelete.setDeletedAt(java.sql.Date.valueOf(
                     LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
```

> Do i need to set zoneid somewhere or its inbuilt?

Edit: It is never the same date in all time zones. So you need to choose in which time zone you want today’s date if that’s what you want. The JVM in which your program is running always has got a default time zone, and that’s what I am taking with `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. The default time zone is typically taken from the operating system. It can also be set explicitly when you start the JVM or from within a program at any time. You may alternatively specify a time zone in the call to `LocalDate.now()`, for example `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/Chihuahua"))`.

> Is this correct?

No, what you were doing was not entirely correct. According to the documentation a `java.sql.Date` must have its time of day set to the start of the day (typically 00:00), which you don’t obtain from the code you showed us. Documentation quote:

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values
> wrapped by a `java.sql.Date` instance must be 'normalized' by setting
> the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the
> particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

From the documentation of `java.sql.Date`.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Documentation of `java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html).

Comment: Do i need to set zoneid somewhere or its inbuilt?

Comment: There’s a default time zone built it, but it may not be what you want. Please see my edit.